# How can I put everything in one line?

Tags: file, perl, file-io

This is my code:

```
 open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
  print $fh "GIF files: \t$gif_nums(Number of files) file(s) $gif_sizes(File size) bytes\n";
  print $fh "HTML files: \t$html_nums file(s) $html_sizes bytes\n";
  print $fh "Total: $total_nums file(s) $total_sizes bytes\n";
  close $fh;
```

MY output is comming like this:

```
GIF files: 1
 file(s) 48835 bytes
HTML files: 1
 file(s) 260 bytes
Total: 2 file(s) 49095 bytes
```

I want output like this :

```
GIF files:   1    file(s) 48835 bytes
HTML files:  1    file(s) 260 bytes
Total:       2    file(s) 49095 bytes
```

How can I get this type of output in Perl?

Comment: Check https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html

Comment: Or alternatively, you could do something like `printf "%10s %5d %20s"` (adapt fields width as needed) if you have an upper bound on the size of the elements (and if you don't, `%*s` might be the solution)

Answer (score 2):

Almost looks like the `$gif_nums` and `$html_nums` variables are probably strings with a newline instead of numbers, hence why it is spreading one `print` statement over two lines.

Use the `chomp` function to remove the newline from your variables would be a good start.

Comment: @Jack: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55431426/edit) to add details of what you have now tried and (most importantly) the **exact text** of the error message you're getting. Just saying "it's not working" and "I got an error" is really not very helpful.